# Where are my ALSA, pulseaudio lib

Tags: fedora, software-installation, compiling, libraries

I tried to install darkice with lame. To compile it, I need ALSA and Pulsaudio:

```
checking for lame library at /usr ... found at /usr 
checking for vorbis libraries at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without Ogg Vorbis
checking for opus libraries at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without Ogg Opus
checking for faac library at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without faac
checking for aacplus library at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without aacplus
checking for twolame library at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without twolame
checking for alsa libraries at /usr/lib/alsa-lib ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without ALSA support
checking for pulseaudio libraries at /usr/lib64/pulseaudio/libpulse ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without PULSEAUDIO support
checking for jack libraries at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building without JACK support
checking for samplerate libraries at /usr ... configure: WARNING: not found, building libsamplerate support
```

I can add with `--with-*-prefix=` a path for this libraries. But I have no idea where on my system I can find them, or what I need to install, to compile with them.

I tried `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`, both don't work.

**My question is where do I get these libraries from?**

system: Fedora release 19 (Schrödinger’s Cat) 3.11.6-200.fc19.x86_64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Its just that you need to install the *-devel rpm's and thats it.

For pulseaudio and alsa it's: `alsa-lib-devel, pulseaudio-libs-devel`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempt to compile this myself I'd be inclined to get the source RPM for `lame` and rebuild that. You can then lean on the package management software to assist in getting the necessary packages installed so that you can rebuild `lame`.

Start with getting an RPM development environment setup. Afterwards you'll need to download the `lame` source RPM. You'll then use the tool `rpmbuild` with the switch `--rebuild` and the `lame` source RPM to build it.

Everything you need is spelled out in this blog tutorial, titled: [Rpmbuild Tutorial].[1](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/?s=rpmbuild). I've also written about it extensively on my blog in [this series of posts](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/?s=rpmbuild).

You can find several source RPMs for `lame` here:

- http://pkgs.repoforge.org/lame/

Comment: I don't really understand your answer, and I think you misinterpret my question 'cause I can and have lame installed. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sirl33tname - From the output it looks as though you were attempting to build `lame` yourself.